# when to use log transformation for income?

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Is it appropriate to use logs on a discrete measure of wealth where the different response options are not linear (i.e., they contain different wealth ranges like $\$500,000-\$749,999$ which is a smaller bucket than $\$1$ million-$\$1.9$ million)?

Is log only appropriate when you have the actual value of income (not just the category it falls in)?

Comment: You can apply log here too.

Comment: I would probably NOT use logs on this. The buckets get bigger as the values go up, so in a sense the log transformation has already been applied in determining the bucket boundaries. You might consider an ordinal-response model, though, e.g. proportional odds.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your analysis.  If your goal is to treat the bins as an ordinal variable, then there would be no point in transforming the data.  However, if you wish to treat the variable as interval or ratio (perhaps you wish to use it as the dependent variable in regression), you could convert the variable into the mean of each range, and then log-transform.  For example, an observation in the 500,000-749,999 range would be:
$log$((500,000+749,000)/2).
In that case, the log-transformation might help make the residuals more approximately normal, which is an assumption of regression.